# Windows local admin disabled. Can I use domain admin to install software on my machine?

Tags: uac, window, windows-domain, microsoft-account

I am new to Security so excuse my dilettante question.
At work my laptop's local admin is disabled and I can't install software as UAC prompts for admin creds.
I was wondering if I get an admin domain account or for instance my local account can become a member of domain admin group, would I be able to install software without UAC giving me hard time?
Thinking about it, is local admin the only option when it comes to installing software to my laptop?

Comment: If you can make your standard user name a member of the local or domain admin user group, you will be able to install software. It seems to me unlikely that your work administrator will do this for you.

Comment: Indeed, this was just a hypothetical question. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: To your precise question, either a local admin or a domain admin can install software. A domain administrator is likely to sign in as themselves to install something for a user.

Comment: Your local account does not exist on the domain.  Your local account would have no privileges on the domain.  Likewise, if your domain account is not already an Administrator,you will be unable to give yourself Administrator permissions on the domain.  **You should have an Administrator on the domain install the software you want installed.**

Comment: Thank you both for elaborating

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes and no.

To get administrator rights, you *must* be a member of the local "Administrators" group. It doesn't matter whether your account itself is local or domain – it still must be a member of the local group.

By default all Domain Admins are indeed automatically added to the local Administrators group. So if you become a Domain Admin, then you indirectly become a local Administrator on every computer as well.

However, I think you misunderstood what a "domain admin" account is. Being in the 'Domain Admins' group doesn't simply give local admin rights to install software – it actually gives admin rights *over the domain itself*, such as creating domain-wide accounts, accessing all other computers, deploying security policies, or even destroying the whole thing. (Having local admin rights is just additional to that.)

So you're unlikely to be added to the Domain Admins group – it's very much overkill for the task, and an unnecessary risk (cue ransomware).

Instead, what you need is to have your domain account added to the *local* Administrators group, on your computer – your workplace's IT team might even do this remotely through Group Policy.

Comment: It does not sound like the author has any elevated permissions currently (local or domain).

Comment: Yes, I don't have any right indeed. However, on your idea that my domain account could be added to the local Admin group. Isn't this a violation of the least privilege principle in security and that's way they didn't grant me local admin, i.e. to prevent attacks like escalating privileges for instance?

Comment: But you're literally asking for those privileges anyway. (Actually what you were asking in the original post violates the principle _far more_ than merely having local admin rights.)

Comment: I was just asking in theory. From a dilettante perspective I was shocked to find out that UAC is something more than  just clicking yes and carry on with whatever you were doing lol. Thank you anyway